# Parse file to get contents in text file and output to new file

Tags: bash

I have multiple text files in a directory with the following contents and I want to loop through them, extract the items in bold and output them into a text file:

> ...
>
> Copy File         ${RESOURCES}/**aXpKcHLe2f.DAT** ${NEWDIR}/File2.DAT
>
> Compare File      Actions ${TEMPLATES}/**KGuovBrMwK** ${NEWDIR}/DT
>
> ...
>
> Copy File         ${RESOURCES}/**9ZzUpgmTy0.DAT** ${NEWDIR}/File2.DAT
>
> Compare File      Actions ${TEMPLATES}/**qpk3BiCvRG** ${NEWDIR}/DT
>
> ..

How would I do this in a bash script? I understand that it requires some regex, but I am not sure where or how to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `find + awk` solution:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec awk -F '/' 'NF>1{sub(/ .*/, "", $2); print $2}' {} +
```

This will print desired output from 2nd column delimited by `/` in each `*.txt` file. If your file extensions are different then you can change this `-name` pattern accordingly.